# How to make distance between captions of close pictures?

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

The captions between the pictures are too close to each other. How can I make some space between them, but do not move pictures itself?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\centering
\subfigure[One two three four five six seven eight ninte ten eleven twelve]{\label{fig:a}\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{A.png}}
\subfigure[One two three four five six seven eight ninte ten eleven twelve]{\label{fig:b}\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{B.png}}
\subfigure[One two three four five six seven eight ninte ten eleven twelve]{\label{fig:b}\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{B.png}}
\caption{my caption}                                                            
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `caption` package and adjust the width of captions for `subfigure`s. `caption` also provides other means to customize your captions, for details refer to its documentation.

Please note that the `subfigure` package is obsolete and you can use either `subcaption` package (which provides `subfigure` environment) or `subfig` package (which provides `subfloat`). I have used `subcaption` package.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption,showframe}   %% remove showframe
\usepackage{graphicx}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{width=0.8\linewidth}    %% adjust here
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.33\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{One two three four five six seven eight ninte ten eleven twelve}\label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.33\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{One two three four five six seven eight ninte ten eleven twelve}\label{fig:b}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.33\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{One two three four five six seven eight ninte ten eleven twelve}\label{fig:b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{my caption}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can make it local by adding `\captionsetup` inside the `figure*` environment (instead of preamble).

```
\begin{figure*}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{width=0.8\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.33\textwidth}
.
.
.
```

[image]

Comment: How to add captionsetup only for a figure, but not to the whole document?

Comment: @msh Put `\captionsetup[subfigure]{width=0.8\linewidth}` inside `figure*` environment. Don't put it in the preamble. Answer updated.